# Docker: make command only fails during auto build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

the build of the following docker image fails during the command:

```
RUN cd /eman2_build && make -j
```

Image and log output: https://hub.docker.com/r/thorstenwagner/docker-yolo-keras/builds/bj9wvm9zc6zgghrkphance8/

However, when I comment out the last two commands the build is successfull. If I then run the last two commands inside the docker image everything works.

Any idea why this command fails only during autobuild?

Best,
Thorsten

Comment: Not sure- but there is a workaround, try to put those command inside a shell script and once everything is up and running, then try to run that shell script externally/internally.

Comment: Like this? RUN echo 'cd /eman2_build && cmake ../eman2 && make -j && make install' > eman2build.sh
RUN bash eman2build.sh

Comment: Yes, try RUN bash eman2build.sh (make sure 1st you need to copy eman2build.sh then provide 777 access to that file and then use the command to get it run). or once the container is running then run that shell script from the external command.You need to play around this, I am doing same kind of thing with one of my docker file.

Comment: I suggest to compile again without the `-j` key, so you can have a clue of what the error is, otherwise the error message is spread across all the log, interleaved with many processes.